Basis for the domain $A[\alpha]$ where $\alpha$ is integral over $A$.
Let’s say we have some domain $T$ and a domain $A$ sitting inside $T$. Suppose that $\alpha \in T$ is integral over $A$ (so $p(\alpha) = 0$ for some $p(x) \in A[x]$). Suppose that $\deg p(x) = d$. Why is it the case that $\{1,\alpha, \cdots, \alpha^{d - 1}\}$ is a basis for $A[\alpha]$ over $A$?

If $p(\alpha)=0$, then $\alpha^d$ (and higher powers of $\alpha$) can be expressed as a linear combination of $1, \alpha,\dots,\alpha^{d-1}$

Right but why are they linearly independent?

If not, there’s a polynomial of smaller degree satisfied by $\alpha$

Why is that an issue?

Prove that if there is a polynomial of degree $d'$ that is satisfied by $\alpha$, then there is a monic polynomial of degree $d'$ that is satisfied by $\alpha$. (Use division in the field of fractions of $A$.) The basis is given by the least such $d'$.

In general there is no basis. Try $k[x^2,x^3]\subset k[x]$.

Just to work out the counter-example indicated by Mohan: Let $k$ be a field. Let $T := k[t]$ be the polynomial ring over $k$ and $A := k[t^2, t^3] \subset T$. Consider the element $\alpha := t \in T$. The polynomial $p(x) := x^2 - t^2 \in A[x]$ with $\deg(p) = 2$ shows that $\alpha$ is integral over $A$. However the set $\{1, \alpha\} = \{1, t\}$ is not linearly independent over $A$: For example, the equation $t^3 \cdot 1 + (-t^2) \cdot t = 0$ with the coefficients $t^3, -t^2 \in A$ is a non-trivial linear relation.
